# add folders to git in Matlab

Tags: git, matlab, github, version-control

i want to start using version control with matlab and github. Is there a way to add entire folders to my repo? i only see the possibility to add one file at a time via "right-click"->"source control"->"add to git".

it would also be nice to add and commit files via command-line. Are there matlab commands for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i installed the git command line and cd'ed into the folder then i used

```
$ git add .
```

to stage all files

Answer (score 2):

If you [install the git command line](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-git-source-control.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop), then you can use [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add-ltpathspecgt82308203) to select all files in a given directroy, like so:

```
git add folder_to_add/*
```

This will add all files in `folder_to_add`. You can also use

```
git add folder_to_add/**
```

to add all files in `folder_to_add` and all of its sub-folders.

Note that git is based around files, not folders, which is why [you can't add an empty folder to git](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F). So think about adding "all files in a folder" rather than "the folder".